# Well water pressure changing rapidly

Tags: well, pressure

I’m hoping someone could help us. We noticed an issue with our water pressure, it seems to fluctuate every 20 seconds or so. We are still able to use our water but it’s become a lot more noticeable. I did a lot of research to try and understand what’s going on and what to test but I would love some confirmation before we order a new water pressure tank.

Some info about our system:
Wellxtrol WX203, 32 gallons

I believe the cut in/cut out should be 40/60 as the pressure switch cuts off at 60, however it doesn’t turn on until 33. I know it should turn on at 38.

The tank itself is laying on its side in the crawl space. I've read this can cause premature rupture of the bladder.

There is no info anywhere about the well pump (on the cap or by the circuit breaker) so we followed a video to measure. We got 9.8 GPM.

When we measured our drawdown, we only got .75 gallons. We were going to drain the tank and check the air pressure to test for a ruptured bladder but with such a small drawdown, we are scared to mess with anything too much.

I have tried to learn as much as I can about this so I pray I’m making some sort of sense. Thank you so much for any help you may be able to offer us.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. If an answer is helpful, please click the large check mark next to it to accept. And, please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.

Answer (score 1):

You almost certainly need a new tank (or bladder if you have a tank with replaceable bladder, though when I had one of those I was not thrilled to find a that a new bladder (no warranty, have fun swapping them) was almost equal to a new tank with new warranty, which made "replaceable bladder" much less of a "feature" in my mind.)

Your pressure switch [may be adjustable](https://download.schneider-electric.com/files?p_enDocType=Instruction%20sheet&p_File_Name=65013-005-98.pdf&p_Doc_Ref=65013-005-98) - look up the instructions for it, as presumably they are not carefully stored nearby given the rest of your system problems.

Beware of simply getting what you have when replacing parts - if it was done wrong once, do it right the next time, don't repeat past mistakes like the sideways pressure tank.

Comment: Having replaced a pressure tank bladder myself, I'm going to 2nd the above answer.  Just buy a new tank and save yourself a lot of headache.  Tanks are not that expensive and generally last 15-20 years or longer.

Comment: Thank you for your help with this. Our crawl space is very small and we have no space on our main floor so I’m guessing I will need to call someone out to do this job. I was hoping it would have been something like a simple swap. My family and I are currently in quarantine so I’m unable to call anyone in the next two weeks, do you think it would hold out until then? 

Thank you again for your help, I sincerely appreciate it!

Comment: Depending on the nature of your crawlspace you might be able to dig out a spot to put your new pressure tank in. After all, if you and the family are stuck for two weeks - covid-project!

Comment: Sadly my husband has a bad back so I don’t think we would be able to. So far our HVAC went, as did our fridge, washer, stove, and dishwasher. I was praying this may have been the one thing that was simple. Ah well, seems right on par with 2020. Lol. Thank you for your help. 